# How to recreate a image src link using html DOM?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I grab other page contents using HTML DOM and  when im grabbing some images it's src's shows like this -

```
<img src="/datas/vt/data=Ay5GWBeob_WIPLDYoIWcfVXxvZu9XwJ55OX7Ag,OfrBKR" style="margin-right: 12px; margin-top: 1px; padding: 1px;" width="270" border="1" height="185">
```

Is there any way to add contents to the image src? example: www.contentgrabbingsitename.com !!!

Like

```
<img src="www.contentgrabbingsitename.com/datas/vt/data=Ay5GWBeob_WIPLDYoIWcfVXxvZu9XwJ55OX7Ag,OfrBKR" style="margin-right: 12px; margin-top: 1px; padding: 1px;" width="270" border="1" height="185">
```

my code:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
```

Comment: Which library are you using to process the HTML DOM?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just edit the attributes, e.g.:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $e) {
    // prefix 'hello' to the src attribute
    if ('/' == $e->src[0]) {
        $e->src = "http://mydomain.com" . $e->src;
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you just save the page.

Comment: This code adds prefix hello to every image src on the page ! I just want to add that prefix to images that have scr like this -   scr="/datas/vt/

Comment: And you never heard of an `if` statement? ;-)

Comment: yes i made a code my self with if and ur code and it works !!!! yehh!! thanks friend....

Comment: if(strstr($e, '/datas/vt')) { }